# event prevent default not working as it should

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I was wondering in the following example why event.preventDefault() is not working? Can someone explain me in details ? thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/qw8fmhap/215/

```
let nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-toggle');
nodeList.forEach((elem) => {
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you expect `event.preventDefault` should do?

Comment: event.preventDefault() from what i know in this context should stop the clicking on the elem. I'm i wrong ?

Comment: Hmmmm, try adding `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: yeah seems that stopPropagation() does  the job and the rest of the code has another problem. because later on it doesn't call another even .. :D :)

Comment: `.preventDefault` is working perfectly on the handlers where it is bound. Is there a reason you neglected to post the full demonstration here as well as a clear explanation of what "not working" means?

Comment: no there is no reason .. :-) https://jsfiddle.net/qw8fmhap/244/ just trying to close the dropdowns when the bs event is fired. and i wasn't sure if stopPropagation would cancel that event .. :D